# How to split single micro-usb to several independent aux channels

Tags: usb, audio, pi-zero, raspbian-buster

I have a Raspberry Pi Zero with Debian Linux running home automation software (Home Assistant). Instead of using different phones' alarm clock for awakening in the morning I would like to manage it in centralized manner on the Pi. The alarm clocks are intended for several bedrooms (parents, kids). They should sound independently in order to awake only those whom they are supposed to awake (i.e. one alarm targets a specific bedroom). To this end I want to put one speaker per bedroom, connect it to the Pi and write automatons that would play sound to the specific speaker on scheduled times. The problem is - my Pi has no aux output at all - only one micro-usb. So my questions are:

1. is there a micro-usb to multiple aux channels cable converter? (I saw only 1 usb to 1 aux so far)
2. if there is such a cable - can Linux kernel handle this and how can I play sound on a specific aux from command line?
3. are there better approaches to achieve the above?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by an "aux channel"? Is that supposed to be some kind of audio interface? Is it an input or an output? What sort of electrical characteristics do you expect?

Comment: have you considered a usb hub with multiple 1 usb to 1 aux (whatever that is)

Comment: You can get analogue switches and use a I2S hat (Pimoroni / Adafruit) to give your analogue out but how about using Bluetooth speakers?

Comment: @ElliotAlderson: to connect speakers hence - multiple audio output.

Comment: @JaromandaX: yes I considered it, but it is too cumbersome - I prefer one 1toN cable. I'll probably end up using both micro-usb slots of Zero. This is actual 1 usb to (1 aux + 1 usb (for power)): [something like this](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/1005001436243927.html?spm=a2g0o.productlist.0.0.1b2b6747Twr7nD&algo_pvid=ee6b2c3f-43fc-4d80-aaeb-aab9aa257887&algo_expid=ee6b2c3f-43fc-4d80-aaeb-aab9aa257887-0&btsid=2100bde316149510623907446e0873&ws_ab_test=searchweb0_0,searchweb201602_,searchweb201603_) just for micro-usb... is there such a thing?

Comment: it may be too cumbersome but you know the parts exist - as opposed to what you want, which does not exist